# Google Cloud Price List

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to parse the Google Cloud Pricing file. And during parsing I encountered

```
"CP-COMPUTEENGINE-OS": {
      "win": {
        "low": 0.02,
        "high": 0.04,
        "cores": "shared",
        "percore": true
      },
      "rhel": {
        "low": 0.06,
        "high": 0.13,
        "cores": "4",
        "percore": false
      },
      "suse": {
        "low": 0.02,
        "high": 0.11,
        "cores": "shared",
        "percore": false
      }
    }
```

**Does anyone have any idea what the "low" and "high" stand for here ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "low" price is what you pay when the machine has as many or fewer cores as the "cores" variable. ("shared" means f1-micro or g1-small). If you have more cores than that, you pay the "high" rate. Note also that the windows "high" rate is per-core.

This is encoding the same rules described at https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#premiumimages

Comment: If you felt my comment fully answers your question, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer to mark the question as answered and give us both a bit of reputation bump